# mysql Or doctrine 2 query [order by MAX]

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-query, doctrine-extensions

can i do this in doctrine or mysql,
NOte that `created` is a `datetime` field, and i don't want to do it by another field as i may need to do it by updated date that is also a datetime field

```
$query = $querybuilder->select(array(
        'obs.insStatus as id',
        'obs.obsStatus as text',
    ))
        ->from('Application\Obs', 'obs')
        ->where('obs.project = :project')
        ->setParameter(':project', $this->projectId)
        ->groupBy('text')
        ->orderBy('MAX(obs.created)', 'DESC');`
```

its giving me error but is there are way to do something like that

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 1645: Error: Expected end of string, got '('

Comment: in mysql you can use max or desc with limit 1 both works same like : select MAX(comments.created) from table_name  or select comments.created from table_name order by comments.created desc limit 1

Comment: Please show us the full query.

Comment: so i cannot do order by Maximum values?